# Adobe Photoshop - how to move the entire group not just a single layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

When I select the group, and then take my mouse and drag to move, I end up moving an individual layer. I end up having to use my keyboard to move things around, but thats very inefficient. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am assuming that I should not have to "Cmd+T" before moving the group everytime!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Make sure you have auto-select disabled. This causes the program to select whatever item you click on instead of the element you have selected in your layer overview.

[image: Auto select in Photoshop]

Comment: To add to this, you can auto-select, but change the dropdown from layer to group.

Comment: Levano: gentleman, scholar, hero.

Comment: The answer didn't work for me, but @Benneb10 's comment did!

Comment: Both worked for me! Like the using @Benneb10's method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that - was driving me crazy - sometimes I think Adobe just invent crap to annoy people, then turn on by default to show off. Why can't they just make an 'Optional New Features' video and leave the user to decide if they want to activate them or not instead of driving everyone crazy by auto-activating stuff and making us run around trying to figure out what the nasty little developers have done now.... grrr.